# How can I add a black outline to my chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a chart that is very similar to the one here I can't seem to figure out how to outline the bars and make sure the fill is in the right order.

[image]

This is the current code ive compiled so far and make a few comments on what I've been trying to fix

```
 #what is a factor in R? It is a categorical variable
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("nyplots Rstudio.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# the fill is not in the right order
# the line colors not good
# no y axis
# facets per Country
#bonus: TOOLTIPS
ggplot( df, aes(x = (Year), 
                y = Percentage, 
                col = Party,
                fill = (Ideology) )  ) +
  geom_col (position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white", "grey", "light grey")) +
  theme_classic() 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

`dput` of data

```
structure(list(Country = c("Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", 
"Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", "Hungary", 
"Hungary", "Hungary", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy"
), Year = c(1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), Party = c("FIDESZ", 
"MIEP", "FKgP", "Other", "SZDSZ", "Munklaspart", "Socialist Party ", 
"FIDESZ", "MIEP", "Other", "SZDSZ", "Socialist Party ", "FIDESZ", 
"MIEP", "FKgP", "Other", "SZDSZ", "Munklaspart", "Socialist Party ", 
"FIDESZ", "MIEP", "Other", "SZDSZ", "Socialist Party "), Percentage = c(28.2, 
5.6, 13.8, 8.3, 7.9, 4.1, 32.3, 41.1, 4.4, 6.9, 5.6, 42.1, 28.2, 
5.6, 13.8, 8.3, 7.9, 4.1, 32.3, 41.1, 4.4, 6.9, 5.6, 42.1), Ideology = c("far-right", 
"far-right", "far-right", "other", "center", "center", "center", 
"far-right", "far-right", "other", "center", "center", "far-right", 
"far-right", "far-right", "other", "center", "center", "center", 
"far-right", "far-right", "other", "center", "center")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Please include the code and data to provide a reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: just posted the code

Comment: Could you use dput to create a minimal example of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that output the graph with detail explaination

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
# Using colors vector with name to ensure the right color was asigned to right one
iodeology_color <- c("grey", "white", "red")
names(iodeology_color) <- c("other", "center", "far-right")
# Convert character to factors with levels -
# ggplot2 automatically order the bar by factor levels
df$Ideology <- factor(df$Ideology, levels = c("other", "center", "far-right"))
df <- df %>% arrange(Ideology, Country)
df$Party <- factor(df$Party, levels = unique(df$Party))
# using forcats::fct_relevel to order "Other before every thing else
# (the 1st one appear to be on top of the stacked bar plot)
df$Party <- fct_relevel(df$Party, "Other", after = 0L)

ggplot(df, aes(x = (Year), 
  y = Percentage, 
  # instead of using col (color) for Party - group as party
  group = Party,
  fill = (Ideology) )  ) +
  # then here color is define as black so it outline the bar with black line
  geom_col(color = "black", position = "fill", size = .5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = iodeology_color) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    # add legend background for easier to read the white fill legend.
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue", 
      size=0.5, linetype="solid"))
```

Output graph

[image]